# VBA - Concatenated String in Autofilter Array not working

Tags: vba, excel-2016

So I have stored all variables in a string and then try to pass that on to the Autofilter criteria, but to no avail.

```
Sub TestAutoFilter()
'Filter based on column Importance.
'PURPOSE: Dynamically Create Array Variable based on a Given Size

Dim myArray()   As Variant
Dim DataRange   As Range
Dim cell        As Range
Dim x           As Long  

'Determine the data you want stored
Set DataRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

'Resize Array prior to loading data

'Loop through each cell in Range and store value in Array
counter = 0
For Each chkbx In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBoxes
    
    If chkbx.Value > 0 And InStr(1, LCase(chkbx.Name), "check") <> 0 Then
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next chkbx

ReDim myArray(counter)
For Each chkbox In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBoxes
    If chkbox.Value > 0 And InStr(1, LCase(chkbox.Name), "check") <> 0 Then
        myArray(x) = chkbox.Caption
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next chkbox

myArrayString = ""
'Print values to Immediate Window (Ctrl + G to view)
For x = LBound(myArray) To counter
    myArrayString = myArrayString & "," & myArray(x)
Next x
'Debug.Print (myArrayString)

myRightString = Left(myArrayString, Len(myArrayString) - 1)
myLeftString = Right(myRightString, Len(myRightString) - 1)
'Debug.Print (RTrim(myLeftString))
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A3:F3").AutoFilter Field:=3, _
                         Criteria1:=Array(myLeftString), _
                         Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

I also tried to replace myLeftstring with the actual array as such `Criteria1:=myArray` but that also didn't work.

Comment: Why don't you use `myArray` directly? You cannot obtain an array from a string. Only by splitting it on a separator, but in this case you already have the array to be used: `Criteria1:=myArray`... Whay did you "stored all variables in a string"?

Comment: Well, because I had tried to do that at first, but it gave me nothing back. So I thought maybe I needed to store it in a string first like you would do it normally with `Array("Criteria1", "Criteria2")` for which it works..

Comment: How did you put the strings in the array? I hope they are not between double quotes... Please, try `Debug.Print Join(myArray, ",")` and post here the result copied from Immediate Window. The array should work **as it is**...

Comment: If I use join I get `Criteria1,Criteria2,` with a trailing comma. I also tried to put it inside array as follows: `Array(Join(myArray, ","))` but still not working.

Comment: @FaneDuru, I added all the code now if that helps..

Comment: I don't know why, but it suddenly worked with just myArray..I really don't know why

Comment: Only due to the fact that using that array is the correct way. I do  not know what (else) wrong you did before...